# Bash script to get server health

Tags: linux, bash

Im looking to monitor some aspects of a farm of servers that are necessary for the application that runs on them.

Basically, Im looking to have a file on each machine, which when accessed via http (on a vlan), with curl, that will spit out information Im looking for, which I can log into the database with  dameon that sits in a loop and checks the health of all the servers one by one.

The info Im looking to get is

```
<load>server load</load>
<free>md0 free space in MB</free>
<total>md0 total space in MB</total>
<processes># of nginx processes</processes>
<time>timestamp</time>
```

Whats the best way of doing that?

EDIT: We are using cacti and opennms, however what Im looking for here is data that is necessary for the application that runs on these servers. I dont want to complicate it by having it rely on any 3rd party software to fetch this basic data which can be gotten with a few linux commands.

Comment: Did you take a look at either [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)?

Comment: ...or munin or any of dozens of other packages out there.

Comment: Or [Munin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/) with a [`nginx` plugin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/nginx)

Comment: Or [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) with [nginx collector](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Monitoring_Nginx_with_the_HTTP_collector)

Comment: We already uses cacti and opennms, however the data is used for different things. This is strictly for application data used by scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Make a cron entry that:

- executes a shell script every few minutes (or whatever frequency you want)
- saves the output in a directory that's published by the web server

Assuming your text is literally what you want, this will get you 90% of the way there:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOAD=$(uptime | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1)
FREE=$(df -m / | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }')
TOTAL=$(df -m / | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
PROCESSES=$(ps aux | grep [n]ginx | wc -l)
TIME=$(date)

cat <<-EOF
<load>$LOAD</load>
<free>$FREE</free>
<total>$TOTAL</total>
<processes>$PROCESSES</processes>
<time>$TIME</time>
EOF
```

Sample output:

```
<load> 0.05</load>
<free>9988</free>
<total>13845</total>
<processes>6</processes>
<time>Wed Apr 18 22:14:35 CDT 2012</time>
```

Comment: This is exactly what Im doing now, however I need to get the CURRENT snapshot of whats happening, not a historical record, even if its 1 min old.

Comment: @k1ljoy -- If you want live stats, then configure a CGI script to call the bash script and capture it's output (and configure your web server to handle that type of CGI).